# Select columns of a Data Frame in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a list of Data Frames:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
```

And I want to select just some of the column of each of this, like:

```
df1 = df1[['column_a','column_e','column_wa']]
```

but I want to make this operatio in a loop

```
for df in df_list:
      df = df[['column_a','column_e','column_wa']]
```

but at the end of the loop each of the data frame have the same columns as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method modifies each of the original dataframes inplace.

```
cols_retained = ['column_a','column_e','column_wa']
_ = [df.drop([c for c in df if c not in cols_retained], axis='columns', inplace=True) 
     for df in df_list]
```

`[c for c in df if c not in cols_retained]` results in a list of all columns in that dataframe that are not in `cols_retained`.  This method will work even if one of the dataframes does not have all of the columns in `cols_retained` (if this is not desired, it is easy to add a condition to ensure the filtered dataframes each have the appropriate number of columns).

Answer (score 0):

Within each loop iteration, `df` gets bound to a DataFrame. Following an operation (selecting some of the columns), a new DataFrame is formed, and `df` gets bound to it. There is nothing there that will modify the original list.

---

Here's a way to do so, however. Say you start with something like this:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1], 'd': [1]}) for _ in range(3)]
```

You can do what you're asking with simple [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
dfs = [df[['a', 'b']] for df in dfs]
```

E.g., note:

```
>>> dfs[0]
    a   b
0   1   1
```

Comment: this only addresses one dataframe.  the question is regards to multiple dataframes.

Comment: @Eric ? I'm using list comprehension on multiple dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

you create a copy of the dataframe without the fields - you don't change the original data frame

use:

```
del df['column']
```

to delete a columns from the original DataFrame

**EDIT**
DataFrame.drop allows you to drop multiple columns in one command:

```
df.drop(['column_a','column_e','column_wa'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: this only addresses one dataframe.  the question is regards to multiple dataframes.